# Can not access to the response from server expressjs

Tags: mongodb, express, next.js

When I click the button I send to the server and then the server responds to me but I can't show it in Chrome console I can only see the response in the network tag.

Client:

```
const Login = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
await axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/login", { userLogin })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

};

Server:

```
  app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body.userLogin;
  User.findOne({ username: email }).then((user) => {
    user.password == password
      ? res.json("Login successfully")
      : res.json("Your password or username is wrong");
  });
});
```

Network tag:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't show it? What did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a json object like that

```
app.post("/login", async  (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body.userLogin;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: email });
  
    if (user.password == password)
      return res.json({ status: 200, msg: "Login successfully" });
    else
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Your password or username is wrong" });
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
  }
});
```

You can then show your error in browser console like that

```
const Login = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000/login", { userLogin })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('response', res);
    });
};
```